# How to stream stdout of wget, curl, aria2c, etc with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, stream

How can I stream stdout of cli apps like wget and curl?

`data` and `readable` events don't seem to fire ***while downloading*** with these kind of cli apps where the only new data is actually a changing one. I actually wanted to extract the download speed and show it in my console app, but those events just don't fire... the `end` event fires alright.

Comment: What have you tried? If I understand you correctly, maybe your problem is that `curl` and `wget` sends the stats over `stderr` and not `stdout`.

Comment: Yep!! You're right... just used `stderr` and got what I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curl` and `wget` sends the stats over `stderr` and not `stdout`.